# "Automatically insert all named arguments" at method call-site, in code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, named-parameters

Say there is a method,

```
void M(int a, int b, int c /* and many more */)
```

Is there a way to transform `M()` to `M(a: .., b: .., c: ..)` at the call-site?

I am using Visual Studio <del>2013 (Ultimate)</del> 2017 Professional with <del>ReSharper 8</del> ReSharper 2018.1. A built-in solution (or extension if such is required) that utilized either would be suitable.

This is similar to [Is there any tools to help me refactor a method call from using position-based to name-based parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550160/is-there-any-tools-to-help-me-refactor-a-method-call-from-using-position-based-t?rq=1), although I expect to start with *no* arguments; and am asking the question 4 years later.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here, but if you just want M(a,b,c,...) to be generated for you... I don't know of a one-shot solution but you could just f12 into the method,copy the signature, CTRL - back to the line you were on, paste, select the method signature, and then quick replace int with ": "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper can do this for you https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Argument_Style.html

Comment: Nice. Just verified it too! This support was added at some more recent than the question (it exists in ReSharper 2018.1, not sure when it was added)- and it's a nice [new] feature to know about!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand your requirement.

You could use a T4Template and generate a partial class with said method arguments. 
Other than that I can only see a params parameter working but this would not solve the named parameter issue.